# GROUP_CONCAT multiple columns as an array or explodable string

Tags: php, mysql

Statement I came up with:

```
   SELECT p.user_id AS started_by,
          p.position,
          p.created AS started_time,
          GROUP_CONCAT(
            c.id,
            c.user_id,
            c.comment,
            c.created) AS comments
     FROM pointers AS p
     JOIN comments AS c
       ON p.id = c.pointer_id
    WHERE p.archive_id = 3
 GROUP BY p.id
```

It gets me:

[image]

What happens is that GROUP_CONCAT() simply concatenates c.id . c.user_id c.comment and c.created. I cannot even explode that value in any meaningful way. (Notice how date and id are together as 1 string).

I don't want to create separate query for comments. OR should I?

IN any case, I need orderby c.created the comments, and have two delimiters. for example:

```
comments => 1,1,text this is!,2014-12-20 17:52:02;3,1,asasd,2014-12-20 20:46:40
```

Comment: You might want to approach this problem from a different way — `GROUP_CONCAT` allows you to use `SEPARATOR` but we cannot sure that the separator remains unique (i.e. not found in any of the field values). Also, `GROUP_CONCAT` has a maximum length of 1024 characters. It might be a good idea to have a separate query for comments.

Comment: @Terry thanks, going that way right now :)

Comment: you  can increase the 1024 byte limit with `SET  group_concat_max_len = 4096;` before exec the query

Comment: @Matteo yes I'm aware of that, but 4096 will be enough? you never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining a separator for the concatenation of the columns and another one for the group itself

```
GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws(',',
                       c.id,
                       c.user_id,
                       c.comment,
                       c.created)
            separator ';') AS comments
```