# Group Concat Two Values Into One field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Group concat is driving me nuts.

I have 1 table 2 columns

```
FRUIT    QUANTITY
APPLE    4
ORANGE   6
```

I'd like to group concat these into one field

```
orange:4, apples:6
```

Comment: It might help for you to check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can `concat()` both columns for each row, then `group_concat()` the results over all rows:

```
select group_concat(concat(fruit, ':', qty) separator ', ') res from mytable
```

You might want to consider adding an `order by` to `group_concat()` in order to get predictable, consistent results.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can list multiple columns and other values in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` call, and it will concatenate them together.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fruit, ':', qty SEPARATOR ', ') AS fruits
FROM yourTable
```

If you have lots of columns that you're joining like this, you could use `CONCAT_WS()` to concatenate them all together with the same delimiter. See [GROUP_CONCAT multiple columns as an array or exolodable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582888/group-concat-multiple-columns-as-an-array-or-exolodable-string)